# This feature doesn't play well with jQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have this feature (netwaver.com/projects/featured-content-gallery-pligg-module/) on my site but it is not working well with jQuery plugin. I was researching and reading online and it says it to change the "$".

But the "$" symbol is inside like: {$featurify} - how would that work? All the example I see is showing the $ symbol outside

Comment: Seems familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892819/switching-from-javascript-to-jquery

Answer (score 1):

They likely mean to enable jQuery's [no conflict mode](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries).

Answer (score 1):

The naming collision is because `$` is a shortcut for `jQuery`. You need to call:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Then, once you do that, you need to assure you're calling jQuery without using the "$"

Many more options and discussion here: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
var j = $.noConflict();
```

Add jQuery library to load after the library causing the conflict. Then run this code. jQuery should be accessible through j now, like:

```
j('.class').test();
```